# Google Play Console - Advertising ID

Tags: google-play, android-permissions

I am using Unity Ads SDK for my app, so do I need to add the permission for Ad ID? My app targets Android 12 (API 31). And how to do it if so?

Answer (score 2):

Add permission to your manifest file like below.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

[Google Play developer answer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to declare that permission until you set your target API to 33 (Android 13) or later.
As described in the documentation - [AdvertisingIdClient.Info.getId()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient.Info#public-string-getid):

> For apps with target API level set to 32 (Android 12L) or older, this permission is not needed.